# selecting data from two tables in two different key spaces of Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, cloud

how to select data from two different tables in two different cassandra Keyspaces. I want to select data from two tables but the tables are in different keySpaces

Comment: You need to create the connection to each keyspaces and then select the table using  the respective connection. If you edit you question sharing how you are implementing your connection or the error, maybe we could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You have two keyspaces `Keyspace_a` and `Keyspace_b`. They have two tables `Table_a` and `Table_b` respectively. Now you connect to your cluster and execute following queries one by one.

1. select * from Keyspace_a.Table_a where key='key_a';
2. select * from Keyspace_b.Table_b where key='key_b';

Use the output at client side as you wish. If you want joins, they are not supported in Cassandra.

I would recomend reading "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide"  for better understanding of Cassandra and its usage. Keep learning.